# Reducing "gamy" flavor of turkey

Tags: turkey, smoking

I'm planning on smoking a turkey for the holidays. I have done that before, and it turned out good on the tenderness and flavor, but still had a very "gamy" flavor. I typically use either hickory or fruit wood (fruit has milder smokiness), lump charcoal, for about 8 hours at 200°F and finish it on high heat in the oven.

I use a salt brine overnight the day before, and typically don't apply much seasoning, mostly just a honey glaze. While cooking I occasionally sprinkle it with Sprite or Seven-Up soda to keep it moist.

Do you have any advice on how to make the meat flavor milder or closer to chicken?

Comment: If you prefer the taste of chicken, why not smoke a big chicken?

Comment: lol. Fair, but you know that thing about traditions ;-)

Comment: Absolutely. I was just curious. Also, it's never to late to start new traditions!

Comment: I've smoked chicken before too, very yummy. Maybe I should try to change the tradition!

Comment: Just use a chicken and _tell_ everyone it's turkey.

Comment: I have the exact same issue as the OP. I've smoked three turkeys and they've come out gamey, especially in the dark meat. I like the taste of turkey. My breast meat has a light turkey flavor. The dark meat just has a really strong turkey 'funk' that I'd like to be rid of. I wonder if a longer brine would help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've never thought of turkey as gamey at all, but that's just my own taste I guess. It sounds to me you want a milder bird, in which case you want to buy a cheap battery bird. Gameyness comes from exercise and diet, the blander diet and less exercise the milder (read blander) bird you get. Don't go free-range, get store-brand.